# Checking for updates on OpenSuse 12.1

Tags: opensuse, update

I have a OpenSuse 12.1 web server as a VPS server. I am logged in as root and I am trying to check if there are any updates available.

I've done this many times before but I am now getting the following error when I run `zypper list-updates`.

```
li462-247:/home/bits # zypper list-updates
Loading repository data...
Warning: Repository 'Updates for openSUSE 12.1 12.1-1.4' appears to outdated. Consider using a different mirror or server.
Reading installed packages...
No updates found.
```

Don't understand what the problem is so any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

12.1 seems to be discontinued:

http://en.opensuse.org/Lifetime

so the update repo is not valid anymore. Probably best to update to a newer version of opensuse ;)